# Export HTML and CSS from Photoshop or InDesign

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, photoshop, adobe-indesign

I am building web site and I've got .psd file of how the site should look like and I can make it manually but it will take time. I was wondering if there is a way to export a Photoshop or InDesign file to HTML without requiring major corrections. There is a way to export from InDesign to Dreamweaver but it messes up pictures and text. Is there some a alternative?

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing that will give you an exact replica of your design in your graphics program converted to good semantic and usable HTML / CSS. i.e. Photoshop does have the slice tool that you can use and then export as HTML, but the resulting file/images wouldn't be considered ideal by any web developer/designer worth their salt.

Hand coding a design for someone experienced shouldn't be too time-consuming. Hand coding will also ensure that you cover all scenarios/intricacies of the design, like responsiveness, SEO, accessibility etc.

There are however some new tools like http://www.csshat.com that are getting good reviews.

And you could always google for PSD to HTML service providers if you're running short of time and don't mind paying to have a good job done.

Comment: you can try Export Kit: http://exportkit.com to get PSD to HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery, Flex and more... in just a few clicks.  Super fast, crystal clean code.  Also supports Responsive CSS3!  Almost perfect replica of your PSD design.  http://exportkit.com/downloads/ - try it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

you can export psd file to html via Site Grinder plugin.

download this plugin via http://www.medialab.com/

Answer (score 0):

[PSD to WEB](http://www.psdtoweb.de/) does this job pretty well.